# Creating Threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to get a thread working in C# to reset the time and run another function alongside it. The code I have is:

```
Thread loopTime = new Thread(this.someFunction);
loopTime.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    ChangeTimeFunction(someTime);
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

I am getting a threading error if I pass in `this.SomeFunction()`. This cannot be used according to Visual Studio. I could have the for loop as a thread but I do not know how to pass in the variable `someTime`.

Is there a way to either pass the variable into the loop if it was a function or call the for loop from within the function.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

someFunction is a recorded methods using Visual Studio. This cannot be used outside the main thread. I would need to put the for loop inside the thread I am creating. Does any one know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include the definiton of someFunction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to either pass the
>   variable into the loop if it was a
>   function or call the for loop from
>   within the function.

.NET has two delegates for starting threads.  The first is `ThreadStart`, which just calls a method with no arguments.

The second is [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx), which calls a method with a single `object` as a parameter.

C# will implicitly create a `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate if you pass a method in the Thread constructor that has an `object` argument.  You then send an `object` to it using the thread's [`.Start(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d.aspx) method.

For example, to make the for loop a thread, assuming someTime is a `DateTime` and including a cast to that effect:

```
Thread loopTime = new Thread(someFunction);
loopTime.Start(someTime);

public void someFunction(object someTime) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        // Note the cast here... I assumed it's a DateTime
        ChangeTimeFunction((DateTime) someTime);
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ R. Bemrose -- The ParameterizedThreadStart link was perfect. Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

I think this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28VS.71%29.aspx can explain what you need to do. It seems the ThreadStart delaget will allow you to pass it a function to execute when the thread is started.

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound like problem of "this" qualifier.

Does your someFunction accept a parameter? If yes you can either:

1. Make it parameterless and pass data thru member field
2. Use can use closure to pass variable from the outer scope.

   ```
   int i = 2;
   Thread t = new Thread(x =>
                             {
                                 i++;                                      
                             });

   t.Start();
   ```